# XCode compiles all source everytime

Tags: xcode, precompiled-headers

XCode compiles all source every time i build project and it takes a lot of time. Looks like precompiled headers don't work. It worked correct before i changed location of project. What shuold i do to make it work?

UPD: it's fixed few minutes ago. I don't know how.

UPD2: It's starts again! XCode compiles all sources every time i build. How to manage this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happened for me also when i changed my MAC time and edited some header files and changed time again in MAC. So i opened the files which are edited after changing time, and saved it again. That solved my problem.Its reason should is in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680161/how-can-i-fix-xcode-compiling-everything-all-the-time/1682356#1682356)